# syntax error : identifier 'D3DCAPS9'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT DIRECTX 9.0 SDK (SUMMER 2004)\INCLUDE\d3d9.h(273) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'D3DCAPS9'
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT DIRECTX 9.0 SDK (SUMMER 2004)\INCLUDE\d3d9.h(359) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'D3DCAPS9'
Error executing cl.exe.
```

i get this when i compile my base for BFH hack.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Please quote the exact, _entire_ error message and the part in your code around any lines mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 2):

try including the correct header file. It should be `D3D9Caps.h`

```
#include <D3D9Caps.h>
```

Of course you need to have the DirectX 9 SDK installed.

Comment: And link with the DirectX binaries, and add the DirectX headers' location to your include paths

Comment: Summer 2004 is many, many, many years out of date. You really need a newer SDK.

Comment: Hm which would u perfer 2010?

Comment: Could you point me to a correct link, im literally pulling my hair out... as i've been constantly trying to fix this error..

Comment: February 2010 might also work: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10084

Comment: I'm sorry, but I guess we cannot help you any further.

Comment: ima get it and re upload it... :)

Comment: @zodyi: then ask your friend to show you how to compile the project.